# Is there a way to make ddr4-2134 working with ddr4-2400?

Tags: windows-10, memory, ddr

Look at screenshot:
[image]

The BIOS correctly recognize all modules, but available memory is 16Gb.

May the problem is spd, because A-DATA works only at 1090MHz while Crucial works at 1067Mhz:
[image]

Is there a way to make all RAM modules work correctly?

**Note**

On windows all modules can be seen, but again only 16Gb is available.

Comment: We need to know the model of your motherboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

B150M-C BIOS 3202
Fix Memory Frequency mismatch issue

Go ahead, upgrade the BIOS!
You can try either v3202 or v3402(newer), but description of v3202 says like that. Download one of them below.

v3202: http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/LGA1151/B150M-C/B150M-C-SI-3202.zip

v3402: http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/LGA1151/B150M-C/B150M-C-SI-3402.zip

Comment: Given that this sounds like exactly the sort of thing that could be fixed by a BIOS update I'm not sure why this answer got downvoted.

Comment: It might be worthwhile to link to the actual support download page as well so that the files can be verified as definitely from Asus, some people can be wary of direct downloads.  https://www.asus.com/uk/Motherboards/B150M-C/HelpDesk_Download/

Comment: Not downvoted right now, and since the domain of URLs are all "asus.com" I think these are all already verified.